# Problem setting Combo Box to a value after Null entered

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a datasheet subform with some bound controls, one of which is a Combo Box (cboItem) with Control Source = item. item is set to Required=Yes in table design. The Combo Box is NOT limited to list (values may be typed).

When the user goes to a 'New Record' row, the cboItem_Enter event gives the cboItem field a value:

```
Private Sub cboItem_Enter()
    If Me.NewRecord Then
        cboItem = 3
    End If
End Sub
```

If the user then erases this (leaving a Null value), then tabs to the next field, I want it to display MsgBox ("Null entered") and then assign a value to the cboItem field again (this is where the error happens).

I have this in Form_Error:

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)

    Select Case DataErr
        Case 3314 'Null value entered
            Response = acDataErrContinue
        Case Else
            Response = acDataErrDisplay
    End Select

End Sub
```

I have the following in BeforeUpdate:

```
Private Sub cboItem_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    If IsNull(cboItem) Then
        MsgBox ("Null entered")
        cboItem = 3 'Error occurs on this line
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

This is the error:

[image]

I have tried the same code in cboItem_Exit and Form_BeforeUpdate. In these cases, no MsgBox ("Null entered") pops up, there is no error, and the new value is NOT set.

I have also tried the same code (without Cancel = True) in Form_Current / Form_AfterUpdate / cboItem_LostFocus. Again, there's no MsgBox pop up, no error, and the new value is NOT set.

Comment: If you update the item itself in the `BeforeUpdate` event procedure then that will fire the `BeforeUpdate` procedure again and again ad infinitum.

Comment: cboItem = 3, might be a data type mismatch issue. Check the field item in your table can accept this value.

Comment: Could use the Change event of cboItem and check whether it's empty or not and if so, show the MsgBox and put the focus back to cboItem.

Comment: user10186832: Yes, I see. So is there a work-around? I could use a public boolean invalidInput and set it to true, then if there's an event that happens after, I could use that event to set the new value. I haven't found such an event so far though...

Comment: vbakim: No, that's not the issue. it is a Number Data Type

Comment: Notus_Panda: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll play around with that idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Notus_Panda for suggesting the use of the Change event. I have done the following, which seems to be working:

```
Private Sub cboItem_Change()
    If Nz(cboItem.Text, "") = "" Then
        cboItem = 3
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If IsNull(cboItem.Text) Then
        cboItem = 3
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Trim(cboItem.Text) = "" Then
        cboItem = 3
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not IsNumeric(cboItem.Text) Then
        cboItem = 3
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If InStr(cboItem.Text, ".") > 0 Then 'contains a decimal place
        cboItem = 3
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If cboItem.Text < 1 Then
        cboItem = 3
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If cboItem.Text > 250 Then
        cboItem = 3
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Can also add a MsgBox in any of the If statements to tell the user it's invalid.

Also thought it's worth mentioning (for anyone interested), the user should know they can hit the Escape key to cancel a new record.

Comment: This could be made shorter with `Len(cboItem.Text) = 0` for the first 3 and a couple of OR statements in the IF's btw

Comment: Yes, true, that would make it a bit neater.

Comment: However, (I think) it would need to be Len(Trim(cboItem.Text)) = 0 , in case the user (for some reason) copy/pastes a string of spaces...

Comment: Trim can't hurt, you're right :)